# Nested elements in custom view using xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have custom StackLayout

```
public partial class CustomView : StackLayout
{
    public CustomView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XamlSample.CustomView"
    Orientation="Vertical"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout x:Name="FirstContainer"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        HeightRequest="40"
        Spacing="0">
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout x:Name="SecondContainer"
        BackgroundColor="Red">
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

The idea is to use this layout in xaml with child elements like this

```
<custom:CustomView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="FirstChild"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="SecondChild"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="Green">
        </StackLayout>
    </custom:CustomView>
```

But main thing that I need is that FirstChild should be child of FirstContainer and SecondChild should be child of SecondContainer. So that I can handle position of child elements in CustomView and use xaml.
I know how to make what I want using code behind it's pretty simple but in this case I need to migrate a lot of xaml elements to code behind.

Comment: a very straight forward approach would be: on your custom view, you can use Children property which gives back all its childre.  so Children[0] would be "FirstChild" stacklayout.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MonRdvEnLigne.Common.Views.Xaml.CustomStackLayout">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout x:Name="FirstChild"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent">
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout x:Name="SecondChild"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       BackgroundColor="Green">
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And

```
[ContentProperty("Elements")]
public partial class CustomStackLayout : ContentView
{
    public CustomStackLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable<View> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you missed that I need to place childs elements in separate containers. In your answer you placed two childs in one container. And I can't add two ContentProperty attributes to custom view or something like this.

Comment: With my solution, you can add n child element. If you want only 2, add just 2 elements.

Comment: Awesome! It would be an even better answer with a short expanation what `ContentProperty` means/does